# why does INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED happens?

Tags: android, manifest

i after i run my app this occours:
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.calculator.app
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED]

i probably deleted or changed something and i don't know what...

My manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.calculator.app" >

    <application

        android:icon="@drawable/studenticon128"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SelectedStyle" >
        <activity
            android:theme="@style/SelectedStyle"
            android:name="com.example.calculator.app.MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            >
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity

            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            android:name="com.example.calculator.app.Analysis"
            android:label="@string/app_name"

            android:parentActivityName="com.example.calculator.app.MainScreen">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.calculator.app.MainScreen"
                />
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANALYSIS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

any ideas someone?

Comment: paste your logcat , to see what's causing this error

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
>             />
> ```

`meta-data` requires an `android:value` or `android:resource` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove one ">" from the first activity

Comment: i removed the ">" sign but it didn't solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced this issue, but it was an issue with the metadata, so what I did was to delete the entire tag with its content. See what I deleted from my Manifest.xml file below. When I deleted this my App installed successfully.

```
<meta-data android:name"com.google.android.actions" />
```

The code shows the data that I deleted from my Manifest.xml file to solve the issue.

Comment: Hi @ShantaIE1, it is always better to have a piece of code than an image on your answer.